# Variable being emptied after a few hours of execution - Any alternative to CONST variables?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking for some inspiration or the best practice to eliminate a bug that is very strange...

In the code below, a little below the class *PDFGenerator*, I'm declaring a **public** variable named **strOutPutPath**, because I use its value in several functions and subs of the complete code... below it's just a snippet to illustrate what I'm dealing with...

During a loop to generate files, randomly, the value of **strOutPutPath** becomes empty. It's random, it happens arbitrarily with any number in the range covered by the **For** loop, but usually above 260 and after the loop is generating PDF files for a couple of hours...

Because **strOutPutPath** becomes empty (And I have no idea why), when an iteration (Usually above 260) attempts to start the process and passes an empty **strOutPutPath** as the value of the argument **/outputdir:**, the software hangs because PDFGenerator.exe receives an empty argument for **/outputdir:** and thus never exits, making the main application to eternally wait for its execution.

My 1st idea was to declare **strOutPutPath** as a public CONST variable in the class, however this is not possible because I have to grab the value of **strOutPutPath** from a registry key in the **Main** sub.

Also, I need to treat the contents of **strOutPutPath** within the scope of **Main** sub (Not shown in the code below), so that's why I grab it from within **Main**.

I may be dealing with a .NET bug or simply using a poor practice that is causing .NET to empty **strOutPutPath** once the application is working for a few hours. I have no idea about the root cause of my problem.

But I'd like to know what would be possible solutions for making **strOutPutPath** to act like a CONST variable once it is populated and treated within the **Main** sub. After that it is not supposed to change anymore and will be called by half dozen functions.

Many thanks!

```vb
Module PDFGenerator
    Public strOutPutPath As String

    Sub Main()
        strOutPutPath = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
            "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OutputPath", "Path", Nothing).ToString

        For i as Integer = 0 To 1000 -1
            GeneratePDFs(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GeneratePDFs(ByRef FileID As Integer) As Integer
        Dim ExecutableArgs As String = " /outputdir:" + Chr(34) + strOutPutPath + 
            Chr(34) + " /nodisplay:true /batch:true"
        Dim psiMethod2 As New ProcessStartInfo

        psiMethod2.UseShellExecute = False
        psiMethod2.WorkingDirectory = Path
        psiMethod2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psiMethod2.FileName = "C:\PDF\PDFGenerator.exe"
        psiMethod2.Arguments = ExecutableArgs
        Dim procMethod2 As Process = Process.Start(psiMethod2)
        procMethod2.WaitForExit()

        Return intExitCode
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Is `Main` the entrypoint for the app, or is it called by anything else? Are there any other places where you write to `strOutPutPath`? I can't see any way for this to be happening from the code you have provided

Comment: Make it a read only property. Example change your declaration in the module for strOutPutPath  to something like  Public ReadOnly Property OutPutPath As String
        Get
            Return My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OutputPath", "Path", Nothing).ToString
        End Get
    End Property. May also want to add checks to make sure the registry path exists.

Comment: _I need to treat the contents of strOutPutPath within the scope of Main sub (Not shown in the code below)_ - Why? This can be a root cause you not showing us

Comment: Hi @Charlieface - Main is the entry point... I don't see how this is possible either, why I'm able to generate more than 260 PDF files without issues...

Comment: *"I need to treat the contents of strOutPutPath within the scope of Main sub (Not shown in the code below)"* Can we have your **actual** code, I suspect something else is going on here

Comment: @RyanRoos - I can't capture the value of the key in the variable declaration. I declare it under the class because I need it to be public, but I need to capture it in **Main** because I need to treat it there too. Thanks for chiming in though.

Comment: @Charlieface it works for over 260 files, and main is never called again and/or the variable redefinition never changes again after being treated in the entry point function **Main**. So whatever is emptying the variable, is not happening in the Main function. The full code is huge and cannot be shared. Sorry.

Comment: My nose smells a multithreading issue / race condition, but without the full code I couldn't possibly say. You need to give us a [mcve] otherwise this is simply not answerable. The fact that *you* think nothing else is going on doesn't necessarily mean that is the case.

Comment: Thanks a million for trying @Charlieface - Much appreciated!

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process should be disposed. Make `PDFGenerator` a class and try the following:

**Note**: You may need to add additional code to get the desired result.

**PDFGenerator.vb**

```
Public Class PDFGenerator

    Private _outputPath As String
    Public ReadOnly Property OutputPath As String
        Get
            Return _outputPath
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New()
        _outputPath = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\OutputPath", "Path", Nothing).ToString()
    End Sub

    Public Function GeneratePDFs(ByRef FileID As Integer) As Integer

        'ToDo: add desired code

        Dim args As String = String.Format("/outputdir:""{0}"" /nodisplay:true /batch:true", _outputPath)

        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("args: " & args)

        Dim psInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()

        'set properties
        psInfo.Arguments = args 'arguments
        psInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 'don't create a window
        psInfo.FileName = "C:\PDF\PDFGenerator.exe"
        psInfo.RedirectStandardError = True 'redirect standard Error
        psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 'redirect standard output
        psInfo.RedirectStandardInput = False
        psInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'If True, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
        psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        'psInfo.WorkingDirectory = ""
        psInfo.ErrorDialog = False

        Using p As Process = New Process() With {.EnableRaisingEvents = True, .StartInfo = psInfo}

            'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
            AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Process_ErrorDataReceived
            AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Process_OutputDataReceived

            'start process
            p.Start()

            p.BeginErrorReadLine() 'begin async reading for standard error
            p.BeginOutputReadLine() 'begin async reading for standard output

            'waits until the process is finished before continuing
            p.WaitForExit()

            'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
            RemoveHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Process_ErrorDataReceived
            RemoveHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Process_OutputDataReceived

            'return exit code
            Return p.ExitCode
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub Process_ErrorDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        'ToDo: add desired code

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
            'ToDo: add desired code
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Process_ErrorDataReceived: " & e.Data)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Process_OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        'ToDo: add desired code

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
            'ToDo: add desired code
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Process_OutputDataReceived: " & e.Data)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```